# Words pair up, unzip, and produce children

Tags: wordplay

Watch in this example as the words PARLOUS and MANIAC pair up and unzip to produce PROSAIC and ALUMNA:

```
PARLOUS    MANIAC


PARLOUS  MANIAC


PARLOUSMANIAC


P R O S A I C
 A L U M N A


PROSAIC
ALUMNA
```

In the example above, we will refer to PROSAIC as the firstborn child because it holds the first letter ("P").

I have created 25 more such word families, but I have only given you the firstborn child.  See if you can determine the rest of the family (i.e., the two parents and the second child).

1. SARDINES
2. FUTURES
3. GENESIS
4. GENTLE
5. CENSER
6. BRAINED
7. PINCER
8. BADDIE
9. POISON
10. GATORS
11. GUSHED
12. WAGONS
13. PORTED
14. SUREST
15. PENNED
16. TRIALS
17. TIPPED
18. CLIMES
19. CRONES
20. TAPERS
21. UNREAL
22. SALTED
23. SACRED
24. GENRES
25. CLOSES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

1 sardines

> sparred fiancees sardines preface

2 futures

> fruitful reeds futures rifled

3 genesis

> green beasties genesis rebate

4 gentle

> greens tolled gentle resold

5 censer

> cleans sheers censer lashes

6 brained

> barbarian deed brained abrade

7 pincer

> pliant cheer pincer lathe

8 baddie

> bearded cites baddie erects

9 poison

> peonies moan poison enema

10 gators

> giant tourist gators intuit

11 gushed

> gauss thready gushed astray

12 wagons

> wear goodness wagons erodes

13 ported

> poop retreads ported operas

14 surest

> scurries sits surest crisis

15 penned

> preening end penned reign

16 trials

> toroidal less trials oodles

17 tipped

> tailpipe end tipped alien

18 climes

> calcium tees climes acute

19 crones

> cardoon bees crones adobe

or

> cartoon mess crones atoms

or

> carrom needs crones armed

20 tapers

> traipse erns tapers risen

or

> traipse errs tapers riser

21 unreal

> unnerve earl unreal never

22 salted

> scarlet peed salted crepe

or

> starlit peed salted tripe

or

> starlit teed salted trite

23 sacred

> scarcer peed sacred crepe

24 genres

> greener less genres reels

or

> green oriels genres reoil

or

> glean creeds genres laced

25 closes

> callous mess closes alums

Comment: Impressive! Was that done without computer help?

Comment: Heck, no! Python and a reasonable dictionary makes this stuff not too tricky. There's was a bit of optimization to get this one working. It would be very hard to do without a computer I think.

Comment: That's what I thought, which is why I asked the question :-). (I agree that it's pretty easy by computer.)